# SSSD (LDAP) sudo password with ssh key based login

Tags: sudo, sssd

I'm trying to get an OpenLDAP server up and running a small set of servers. Some of the users naturally need root/sudo access.

The OpenLDAP is setup to use ssh keys for login using https://github.com/AndriiGrytsenko/openssh-ldap-publickey

There is a group named sudo for the purpose on the ldap server. The clients are running SSSD for the setup, all systems are running Ubuntu Server.

The `sssd.conf` from a client:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
domains = user-server

[domain/user-server]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
sudo_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldap://user-server
cache_credentials = False
ldap_search_base = dc=user-server
ldap_sudo_search_base = ou=sudo,dc=user-server
```

The `nsswitch.conf`

```yaml
passwd:         files systemd sss
group:          files systemd sss
shadow:         files sss
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis sss
automount:      sss
```

It seems that the `sudo` command is working if I have made an ssh password login on the machine prior to running `sudo`, but if I haven't it will keep asking for a password as if it isn't looking up the password.

If the user password is changed it has an effect on all working machines. Same if I remove the user from the sudo group it does lose access as expected, and access is regained when the user is added to the group again.

How do I get my `sudo` to check the password against my ldap as expected?

**Edit: the comment from @ognjen led me to search a bit and realized that this log might be helpful:**

from `auth.log`:

```
Apr  8 14:44:36 client-machine sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Apr  8 14:44:40 client-machine sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Apr  8 14:44:40 client-machine sudo: pam_sss(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=rohdef uid=10000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=rohdef rhost= user=rohdef
Apr  8 14:44:40 client-machine sudo: pam_sss(sudo:auth): received for user rohdef: 9 (Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info)
```

**Edit part 1: sudo and pam details per @ognjen suggestion:**

*Personal not: compared these with the working machine, and they are virtually identical. Isn't it SSSD that should take care of pam and whatever over layers are needed, and not sudo? Can anyone confirm?*

```
rohdef@client-machine ~ [1]> ldd (which sudo)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffff91dba000)
        libaudit.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x0000ffff91d14000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x0000ffff91cdb000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x0000ffff91cc7000)
        libsudo_util.so.0 => /usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0 (0x0000ffff91c9b000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffff91b22000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffff91d88000)
        libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x0000ffff91b0d000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x0000ffff91a7f000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000ffff91a6b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000ffff91a3b000)
```

```
rohdef@client-machine ~> sudo -V
Sudo version 1.9.1
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.9.1
Sudoers file grammar version 48
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.9.1
Sudoers audit plugin version 1.9.1
```

```
rohdef@client-machine ~> sudo -L
sudo: invalid option -- 'L'
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
```

**Edit part 2: investigations from logs @Guser314 pointed towards**

After digging in the logs I found one curious thing. The logs for the LDAP from SSSD varies quite a lot from the working and defunct machine.

Logs from the defunct: https://pastebin.com/05p2KszE
Logs from the working: https://pastebin.com/t6av2xdy

Log note, I have added a few blank lines for readability, no lines have been removed. Logs correspond to exactly one attempt at `sudo` (there's no change from repeated attempts)

Judging by the logs it seems that the one that haven't run a password login is basically just giving up looking up the service

Comment: Have you enabled the sudo responder with `sudo systemctl enable sssd-sudo.socket` as noted [here](https://sssd.io/docs/design_pages/systemd_activatable_responders.html).

Comment: Are you running sudo that you installed from source or sudo distribution package? It is possible that there is no pam support in the sudo package that you are using.

Comment: @Guser314 I hadn't :/ it doesn't seem to work though. I'm looking in to the configs they mention on you link, might answer my problebs

Comment: @ognjen I'm running the distro package from Ubuntu 20.10, I think it has pam, but I'm not sure how to check, but indeed that might be an important point :)

Comment: @ognjen added log details from auth.log to the question. Judging by the logs I would say that pam is enabled, but the `securitty` error might be interesting

Comment: To check sudo support for pam run these 1 - ldd `which sudo`

To check if sudo is compiled with PAM

2 -  sudo -V

To check version of sudo

3 -  sudo -L

Comment: Troubleshooting sssd sudo [here](https://docs.pagure.org/sssd.sssd/users/sudo_troubleshooting.html). Also has ways to ask for help. Notes the use of `sudoers: files sss` in nsswitch.conf. I have it working on 20.10 server test vm but only using files for sudo. Noted all sssd sockets enabled by default after sssd, sssd-utils, sssd-dbus installation. Using Google LDAPS.

Comment: @ognjen did as suggested, output added to the question. There seems to be no pam - however, that's also the case on the working comparison machine. I'm not confident that this is the problem - after all, isn't that the entire purpose of having SSSD deal with this, that tools like `sudo` should not be aware of things like pam?

Comment: @Guser314 digged a bit in the debugging logs from what I found playing around on the sites you linked to and various sub sites. I edited the question with the most eye catching difference so far. It looks like SSSD just "gives up" communicating with LDAP on the machine that won't communicate

Comment: @Guser314 your links did the trick with guiding me to track the cause. Turns out I didn't copy the root certificate (CA) to the client :( Bugger, I feel stupid now. Would you be kind and create an answer, with the links you provided and that the root certificate should be present, so I can award you the points?

Comment: @ognjen as you can see the solution was found. Thanks a lot for your effort and help. Keep up the good work, it's hugely appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my consolidated list, glad it helped:

Make sure the sssd responder sockets are enabled, see [here](https://sssd.io/docs/design_pages/systemd_activatable_responders.html). After a fresh install of 20.10 server on a vm I noted that a subsequent apt install of sssd, sssd-utils, sssd-dbus resulted in all responder sockets being enabled. Though many times I've had to enable the responder sockets I needed.

Check the certificates (client and server). See the [FAQ - Authentication fails against LDAP](https://sssd.io/docs/users/faq.html#authentication-fails-against-ldap). I noted for Google LDAPS I needed `ldap_tls_reqcert = never` in sssd.conf because [LDAPS](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9089736?hl=en#zippy=%2Csssd-red-hat-enterprise-and-centos) requires [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and CentOS 7,8 and Ubuntu 20.04 do not provide the same resulting in Google sending back a self signed certificate.

Finally, dig into the logs by following the [Troubleshooting SUDO](https://sssd.io/docs/users/troubleshooting/sudo_troubleshooting.html).

Comment: One side comment, I actually didn't need the sockets enabled (or they just are by default in my setup) :) but it's definitely needed for some setups indeed :)